# Is there a resource for chess puzzles that are altered just enough to discourage easy engine use to solve?

Tags: engines, puzzles

I'm hosting a chess night and would like to post a few wallchart puzzles but would like to discourage folks from secretly whipping out their phone's chess app/engine and scoring points unfairly.

For example, something like this *every-Russian-schoolboy-knows* endgame breakthrough position here with white to move where removing the Kings renders the position **invalid/illegal** by most engines, yet still has enough context to give a person a visualization/calculation challenge if they've not seen it before.

[image]

Comment: How about give them problems that engines can't solve, like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/b3pa4f/puzzle_i_cant_do_reach_this_position_in_4_moves/

Comment: suggestion: chess960 puzzle involving castling. they'd have to select enable castling...hmmm...guess that's not much of a hassle compared to adding the kings...well maybe chess960 puzzle involving castling and the no kings thing?

Comment: @Akavall you mean retrograde?

Comment: here's some retrograde analysis examples in regular chess puzzles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrograde_analysis#Castling_and_en_passant_conventions it's like regular chess puzzles BUT you don't know the last move YET you need to know the last moves to answer

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage

Comment: What kind of idiot would do that? If someone wants a calculation challenge, they have it in front of their eyes. If someone doesn't want the challenge... well, who cares?

Comment: @David idiots who want to appear smart?

Answer (score 12):

You're not going to be able to do this if your attendees actually want to cheat. If you give me a position without kings, I can simply edit the chessvision analysis board by putting a king somewhere I think is reasonable and get around your system.

However, if instead of preventing them from cheating, you encourage everyone to work together in teams on positions (and make sure the puzzles aren't too hard so that frustrated players will seek to quit the charade and bust out an engine), you're likely to make a better environment for everyone. Hopefully you don't have a big prize to the winner (or winning team) as well. For instance, I would suggest something non-monetary. If the only thing someone is likely to get out of the puzzle night is the satisfaction of a job well done, then nobody is likely to cheat.

Comment: "If the only thing someone is likely to get out of the puzzle night is the satisfaction of a job well done, then nobody is likely to cheat." - There's a lot of cheaters even in games where there's nothing to win. It's blaffling but online video games are crippled by cheaters.

Comment: @Echox I know it was just a typo, but blaffling might be my new favorite word

Comment: @Echox: IMHO the online cheating problem is largely a function of anonymity. I doubt those people would cheat if they had to do it live, in person, under their real names.

Comment: @kevin so not for halloween then